# Prove the equality for all positive integers

Tags: combinatorics

$$\sum_{k=0,\ k\text{ even}}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k} = \frac{3^n+(-1)^n}{2}$$

Prove for all positive integers $n$.

I am trying to find a combinatorial proof (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the coefficient of $x^{n-k}y^k$ in $( x + 2y )^n$.  This is 
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right) 2^k$$

When $x = 1$ and $y = 1$, we get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right) 2^k = 3^n$$

When $x = 1$ and $y = -1$, we get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right) 2^k (-1)^k = (-1)^n$$

Taking the sum of these, we get:

$$2\sum_{k=0,k\text{ even}}^n \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right) 2^k = 3^n + (-1)^n$$

And the result we want is achieved by dividing both sides by $2$.

Comment: Good answer, though OP wants a combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Combinatorial proof**

Consider the number of ways to color $n$ distinguishable objects Red, Yellow, and Blue, such that there are an even number of objects colored red or yellow.
We need to prove that both the LHS and RHS count this number.

**LHS:**
To paint the objects in this way, we first choose $k$ objects out of the $n$ to be red or yellow. $k$ must of course be even.  Then there are further $2^k$ ways to decide which of the $k$ objects are red and which are yellow.

**RHS:**
There are clearly $3^n$ ways of coloring the objects Red, Yellow, and Blue in general.
Now, suppose go through a given coloring of the objects and find the *first red or blue object* and switch it from red to blue or vice versa.  Given that there is at least one red or blue object, this procedure switches the number of combined red and yellow objects from odd to even or vice versa, and moreover, if we carry out the procedure twice, we are left with the same coloring we started with.  Therefore, this procedure is a bijection between the following two sets:

- (1) The set of colorings with at least one red or blue object, and an even number of combined yellow and red objects.
- (2) The set of colorings with at least one red or blue object, and an odd number of combined yellow and red objects.

We care about the colorings of type (1).  The only coloring that does not fit into one of the two categories is if we color everything yellow.
If $n$ is even, this coloring is valid, so we add one to double-count it and then divide the total number of colorings by $2$.  If $n$ is odd, this coloring is invalid, so we subtract it off and then divide the total number of colorings by $2$.  Thus our answer for the number of colorings is
$$
\frac{3^n + (-1)^n}{2}
$$
as required.